# Playing an animation on a trigger collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have looked this up, yet nothing worked for me.
I have an animation, called 'gemAnimation1', and I have a box collider set to trigger. When it collides with the player, I want it to switch animations. This is the code I pieced together, but it doesn't work.
The trigger for the animation 'hasTouched'.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class gemCollider : MonoBehaviour {

    private Animator animator;

    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
    void Update ()
    {

    }

    void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("hasTouched");
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

This is a screenshot of the gameobject the script is attached to.
[image: gameobject]
[image: animator]

Comment: Can you post screenshot of the object this script is attached to? The "Inspector" tab. I need to see the setting of the Animator  component. Also, use a simple `Debug.Log` inside `OnTriggerEnter` and see if that's being called at-all

Comment: posted the screenshot, and for some reason it's not being called at all. I checked with `Debug.Log` like you suggested

Comment: In the screenshot, you have to expand the animator component then take a screenshot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `OnTriggerEnter` function is for 3D GameObjects.

You are using `SpriteRenderer` and `BoxCollider2D` which are both for 2D GameObjects. The `OnTriggerEnter2D` function with `Collider2D` as argument must be used.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    animator.SetTrigger("hasTouched");
}
```

*Note:*

You **must** also attach `Rigidbody2D` to one of the 2D Objects in order for the `OnTriggerEnter2D` function to be called. I don't see `Rigidbody2D` in your screenshot.